# ToString() number formatting

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a value in a double of 0.000013 and want to output to text as 0.000013 but don't want to specify a fixed precision. .ToString("F") does not work because it gives 0.00.  Does anyone know the correct specifier for formatting the number ideally limiting to 6 dp but I want values like 0.123 to come out as 0.123 not 0.123000?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you might want:

```
x.ToString("0.######")
```

See ["custom numeric format strings"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) in MSDN for more details.

Comment: Now I remember using that before. Cheers!

Comment: @James Don't forget to accept Jon's answer, if that's what you were looking for.